# Apply Entity Framework migration as a patch

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework Code First migrations to control my database versioning. We have encountered a critical issue in production, which was already noticed and fixed in QA environment, but now needs to be applied to PROD.

The problem is that current latest PROD migration is far not the one that precedes the one we need to apply to fix the issue. I.e., the latest one in PROD is, for example, Migration1. Since that, we have developed Migration2, Migration3, ..., MigrationN-1, MigrationN, MigrationN+1, ... We need to apply MigrationN to PROD, but we cannot apply all intermediate ones, as they are not yet releasable (we are sure, though, that MigrationN can be applied to PROD, as it is not based on any of intermediate ones).

We can cherry-pick the relevant application code changes and prepare a hot-fix deployment, but we cannot do the same with migrations, as if after that we want to have a regular deployment, all intermediate migrations (2 - N-1) will then be ignored, if I get it right.

What should we do?

Comment: What did you end up doing here?

Comment: @user1334007 I do not remember :) We did not work out any elegant approach, so in that particular case we probably worked it around by either not changing the database at all, or changing it by a script and making migration code check if the required changes are in fact there already before applying changes.